# No permissions found in manifest for: []10

Tags: flutter, dart

## I want to get  permissions to download images to image gallery for android.  I tried everything. I am using   permission_handler: ^11.3.0. That's my code which I found here:

`

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class PermissionService {
  // Check and request permission for accessing photos or storage based on platform
  static Future<bool> permissionPhotoOrStorage() async {
    bool perm = false;
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      perm = await permissionPhotos();
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final AndroidDeviceInfo android = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
      final int sdkInt = android.version.sdkInt ?? 0;
      perm = sdkInt > 32 ? await permissionPhotos() : await permissionStorage();
    }
    return perm;
  }

  // Check and request permission for accessing photos
  static Future<bool> permissionPhotos() async {
    bool hasPhotosPermission = false;
    final PermissionStatus try0 = await Permission.photosAddOnly.status;
    if (try0 == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      hasPhotosPermission = true;
    } else {
      final PermissionStatus try1 = await Permission.photosAddOnly.request();
      if (try1 == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        hasPhotosPermission = true;
      }
    }
    return hasPhotosPermission;
  }

  // Check and request permission for accessing storage
  static Future<bool> permissionStorage() async {
    bool hasStoragePermission = false;
    final PermissionStatus try0 = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (try0 == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      hasStoragePermission = true;
    } else {
      final PermissionStatus try1 = await Permission.storage.request();
      if (try1 == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        hasStoragePermission = true;
      }
    }
    return hasStoragePermission;
  }
}
```

`

> that's my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Required permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:label="vizox_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

            <!-- Intent filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Metadata for Flutter embedding -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>

    <!-- Queries -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

`
//but I get only "No permissions found in manifest for: []10" and denied permission/
I Have tried everything, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package, it can download any file in the download folder (As per knowledge after android 12 you need to download file in cache folder and form cache folder you can move file to download folder , please current me if I'm wrong)[Flutter file downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_file_downloader)

Comment: but it can't be used for iOS :(